# Cannot Create Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this SQL query to create a table but does gives error in my REFRENCES AT line 13. This is my query

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM (
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    TYPE VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL, 
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
    SIZE FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    SIZE_TYPE VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
    MANUFACTURE VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL, 
    SECTION VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL, 
    PRICE FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    LEVEL INT(1) NOT NULL, 
    AISLE_ID INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID), 
      FOREIGN KEY (AISLE_ID), 
    REFERENCES aisle(AISLE_ID)
    );
```

Comment: what is the exact error? is AISLE_ID a PK in another table?

Comment: Show create statement for table `aisle`

Comment: yes the AISLE_ID is a primary key in another table. the other table name is aisle with these column aisle_id, X, Y, width, height

Comment: Remove the `,` after `FOREIGN KEY (AISLE_ID)`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM (
ID INT NOT NULL, 
TYPE VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL, 
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
SIZE FLOAT NOT NULL, 
SIZE_TYPE VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
MANUFACTURE VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL, 
SECTION VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL, 
PRICE FLOAT NOT NULL, 
LEVEL INT NOT NULL, 
AISLE_ID INT NOT NULL

PRIMARY KEY (ID) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (AISLE_ID)   REFERENCES aisle(AISLE_ID)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FOREIGN KEY (AISLE_ID), 
REFERENCES aisle(AISLE_ID)
```

Is wrong and should be:

```
FOREIGN KEY (AISLE_ID) REFERENCES aisle(AISLE_ID)
```